# How to use JavaScript functions in Vue directives?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

Assume I have a JS function like this:

```
function myFunc()
{
   return true;
}
```

Now, I want to show an element if the output of is true:

```
<p v-if="myFun()">I am Test</p>
```

I know I can write this `myFunc` method inside Vue `methods` but I don't want this.

Any idea would be great appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can point to your function in many ways. One of these:

```js
var myFunc = function(){
 return true;
}

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  methods : {
    yourFunc() {
      return myFunc();
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <p v-if="yourFunc">test</p>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1nnav731/

Comment: This might be insufficient because if you use a computed property the result is cached based on its dependencies, and will only re-evaluate when some of its dependencies have changed.

Answer (score 0):

You can link your vanilla function in the methods section
`methods:{ myFun: myFun}`

or write your own directive:

```
Vue.directive('visible', function (el, binding) {
    el.style.visibility = binding.value ? 'visible' : 'hidden';
});
```